# Reading the content of a directory inside my project's webcontent folder

Tags: java, spring, path, relative-path, portlet

How to use a relative path to read the content of a directory kept inside the Web content folder of my PORTLET application (using spring framework). As I have found out the resources (XMLs, property files) can be read using resource loader or `class.getResourceAsStream()` but nothing works for accessing the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the classloader you should be able to get hold of the folder.

For example if you have a "templates" folder in you classes dir:

```
try {
  URL u = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("templates");
  File f = new File(u.getFile());
  File[] dir = f.listFiles();
  for(int i=0;i<dir.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(dir[i].getName());
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Perhaps your container is restricting access based on the relative path?